# ReactJS render a OBJ.map based on values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reactjs-flux, reactjs-native

I am trying to render a set of `<div> </div>` based on the items that are in an object but I don't want to have to specify the name of the items in the object in order to display them.

In the example below I want the WorkObjectID and WorkObjectVal to be dynamic and not static.  If I add the tempObject to the object it will not be displayed when the data is rendered because I did not define it in the miniTable.

I would like to specify which ones will be shown by sending them if possible in the `var WORKOBJECTSVALS = {}`.

```
  var WORKOBJECTS = [ {
                      WorkObjectID: "1", WorkObjectVal: "First",
                      TempObject1: "55", TempObject2: "Denied" 
                      }, 
                      {
                       WorkObjectID: "2", WorkObjectVal: "Second",
                      TempObject1: "110", TempObject2: "Allowed" 
                      }];
  var WORKOBJECTSVALS = {"WorkObjectID", "WorkObjectVal", "TempObject1" };

  render: function () {
    var miniTable = this.state.WORKOBJECTS.map(function(val) {
      return (
         <div> {val.WorkObjectID} </div>
         <div> {val.WorkObjectVal} </div>

      );
    });
    return(
      {miniTable}
    );
}
```

In the example above I would like the `TempObject1` to be displayed but not the `TempObject2`.  If I decide in the future that I would like the `TempObject2` to be added into the div I would only need to add it to `WORKOBJECTSVALS`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is work with the property names since those are the key. `Object.keys` returns an array of property names. Then add a `filter` before the `map` so that the unwanted property names are removed.

Here's a modification of your example that starts by using `Object.keys` (Note the changes in definition of WORKOBJECTS and WORKOBJECTSVALS so they are both objects and not arrays)

```
var WORKOBJECTS = { WorkObjectID: "1", WorkObjectVal: "First",
                    TempObject1: "55", TempObject2: "Denied" };
var WORKOBJECTSVALS = { WorkObjectID: true, WorkObjectVal: true, TempObject1: true };

render: function () {
  var workObjects = this.state.WORKOBJECTS;
  var miniTable = Object.keys(workObjects).
    .filter(function(keyName) {
      return WORKOBJECTSVALS[keyName];
    })
    .map(function(keyName) {
      var workObjectID = keyName;
      var workObjectVal = workObjects[keyName];
      return (
         <div> {workObjectID} </div>
         </div> {workObjectVal} </div>
      );
    });
  return(
    {miniTable}
  );
}
```

And if WORKOBJECTSVALS has to be an array, you can change the filter to do this. However it is less efficient, especially if the array is large

```
.filter(function(keyName) {
  return WORKOBJECTSVALS.indexOf(keyName) !== -1;
})
```

Comment: Your method works but if I pass WORKOBJECTS with more than 1 set of data it is not adding each one, IE:
var WORKOBJECTS = [{ WorkObjectID: "2", WorkObjectVal: "Sec", TempObject1: "44", TempObject2: "Denied" }, { WorkObjectID: "1", WorkObjectVal: "First", TempObject1: "55", TempObject2: "Denied" }];

Comment: If WORKOBJECTS is an array of objects, take the code I wrote above as the core for dealing with each object within the array. You can, for example, use forEach to wrap the above core and then concatenate the resulting arrays.

Comment: Thanks.  I did just that, looped all the arrays in WORKOBJECTS and pushed the resulting value of each miniTable into a new Array and displayed that and it worked exactly how I wanted.